# Can't remove an item in $PATH (Xamarin Workbooks)

Tags: bash, macos

The following directory no longer exists on my MacBook Pro after I uninstalled Visual Studio Community Edition for Mac.  I can copy and paste it from the $PATH though here:

```
/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

It's still in the $PATH but I can't tell where it is being set

```
~ $ grep -n SharedSupport ${HOME}/.bash_profile
~ $ grep -n SharedSupport ${HOME}/.bashrc
~ $ grep -n SharedSupport ${HOME}/.profile
~ $ grep -n SharedSupport ${HOME}/.zshrc
~ $ grep -n SharedSupport ${HOME}/.zprofile
~ $ grep -n SharedSupport ${HOME}/.zlogin
```

Any ideas how to remove it from the $PATH?  I uninstalled it so naturally the terminal can't find the folder.  Now I can't find where it's being exported to PATH so I can remove it.

Comment: Have you looked in the profile support code in `/etc` — `/etc/profile`, `/etc/zprofile`, etc?  There's also `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, invoked from `/etc/profile` — read `man path_helper` (and then look in `/etc/paths.d`). Consider adding `set -x` as one of the first lines in your `.profile` or similar files, so you can see what's being executed. Be cautious though; use `set +x` to turn the tracing off, and the damage may already be done before your profile is run. Consider adding `echo "PATH=$PATH"` at strategic points too. Keep an undamaged window open and an unbutchered copy of your files.

Answer (score 4):

Just figured it out! Turns out it stores its paths in a file in `/etc/paths.d` called Xamarian,  like Jonathan Leffler commented. So in order to delete it, we'll need to:

- Open a terminal, this can be `iTerm`, `Terminal`, etc.
- CD Into the Directory
  `cd /etc/paths.d`
- Remove the file called xamarian with [rm](http://man.cx/rm),
  `rm -rf xamarian`

That's it!

Comment: While correct to deal with files in /etc/paths.d , the solution is overkill for the need.  I can just edit the appropriate file.  Nice to learn some bash code here but this is prone to mistaken deletion.

Comment: @WalterSpicer Sorry, just fixed it.

Comment: I agree with Walter; a solution that informs one of what the problem is and teaches the questioner what needs to be fixed is better than an answer that says "here, use this code instead". Never a great idea to paste stuff into your terminal without understanding precisely what it is and does, and why. That said, congrats on your first answer! Keep 'em coming! :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, there is a file called `workbooks` in `/etc/paths.d`.
Open the file by vim and edit it